# Deleting unused DEMs in a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, dem, delete

When I download DEMs for a diagonal section of coastline, I am forced to download a rectangular area, which leaves gigabytes of unused data. I want to delete the DEM files for the areas I don't need.

After building my map in QGIS, by importing ASC files as raster layers, is there a way to draw a selection, and remove all layers within that selection or another quick way to delete unwanted DEMs/ASC files?

[This describes how to select features within a layer for deletion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42164/deleting-multiple-features-easily-in-qgis). My goal is to select *layers* on the map for deletion.

Comment: The end-goal is to delete the files from the hard drive. Whatever achieves that goal in the fewest steps is the ideal solution.

Comment: Easier is to select all you need and delete everything else.

Comment: mmmmm not sure how to do it in QGIS, I would do it programatically in linux using a combination of linux-based tools and GIS tools (e.g., gdal). I would first find a way to filter the ones I need (perhaps you can select them within a region of interest? or filter them by their names?) and then move them to an another directory. This would be my first practical attempt to solve this.

Comment: Thanks @Gery - someone helped me find a solution today which matches your idea: merge raster files into one layer first, create a polygon shapefile representing the areas you want to keep, then "clip raster by mask layer" using that shapefile. Posted the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Merge all the raster layers.
   Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge
2. Draw a polygon shapefile representing the area you wish to keep.
   Layer>Create Layer>Shapefile (polygon)
3. Crop the merged raster file using the shapefile as a mask, save permanently.
   Raster>Extraction>Clip raster by mask layer
4. Delete original raster files!

Thanks to [QGIS Community - Official Virtual Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/qgiscommunityofficialvirtualgroup/posts/2096205770557963/) for helping me find the solution.